# Prove that the range of Fourier transform is dense

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f\in L^2(T)$. and $\hat{f}(k)=\int^1_0 f(x)e^{-2\pi ikx}dx$. Define $e^{2\pi ikx}=e_k$. Then the map $f\to\hat{f}$ is a linear isometry from $L^2(T)$ to $\ell^2(Z)$. Prove that the range of this map is dense in $\ell^2(Z)$. Then conclude the range of this map is equal to $\ell^2(Z)$.

Since $\ell^2(Z)$ is complete thus the conclusion part is fine. for the dense part, for any function $g\in\ell^2(Z)$ we need to find a function in the range of Fourier transform that $||f-g||_{\ell^2}<\epsilon$. Then I am stuck.

Comment: Well, the compactly supported sequences (in other words, sequences with only finitely many nonzero values) are dense in $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Do you wanna show that the range of Fourier transform is dense in the set of compactly supported sequences?

Comment: The point is: if you can show that every compactly supported sequence is in the range of the Fourier transform, then that implies the range contains a dense set, so the range is also dense.

Comment: Is that true? Any compactly supported sequence has a preimage of Fourier transform?

Comment: Sure.  The Fourier transform is linear, so it's enough to show $(\ldots, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, \ldots)$ with $1$ in the $k$ position is in the image for each $k$ (since those span the linear subspace of compactly supported sequences).